# \setlength{pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} not working in sharelatex

Tags: errors, lengths

I am writing a paper for AAAI-18, which requires the following commands to be pasted near the top of the document:

```
\setlength{pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{pdfpageheight}{11in}\\
```

Neither of these commands seem to work in sharelatex.  Is there something I can do in sharelatex (maybe add a .sty file?) to fix this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: Use the geometry package, and it's options, much safer

Comment: Perhaps you're using a `\documentclass` that changes your settings. It would be helpful if you can provide code that replicates your results.

Comment: ? Aren't lengths named by something beginning with a backslash? Maybe that's the problem, but then it would have nothing to do with ShareLaTeX. `pdfpagewidth` → `\pdfpagewidth` and `pdfpageheight` → `\pdfpageheight`?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add always a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: this is unrelated to sharelatex, it is simply a syntax error you are missing a `\ ` before the lengths and conversely the `\\ ` at the end should be removed.

Comment: Don't put a `\\ ` after a “paragraph” consisting of nothing but a `\setlength` command. There is no line here to end.

Comment: David Carlisle's suggestion fixed the error.

Comment: @AliceM. Don't put `\\ ` after a paragraph, either :-).

Comment: @cfr Yeah, I know, I just didn't know what word to use. I kinda meant “a paragraph of lines of code” or something xD

Comment: @AliceM. I figured you knew. I wasn't sure if the OP did.

Answer (score 3):

Add a backslash before `pdfpagewidth` and `pdfpageheight` and remove the two backshlash in the end:

```
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
```

And should work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is technically right, but maybe you could explain your change within the post (adding the backslash).